# additional information collection was modified after the enumerator was instantiated

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety

In the following code I get the error "despite the use of the lock statement" additional information collection was modified after the enumerator was instantiated ". I'm glad you helped me.

```
    private void TextView()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            lock (_kilit)
            {
                if (isFiveSecond == 5)
                {
                    panel1.Visible = true;
                    label1.Visible = true;
                    label1.Text = "TEST";
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    panel1.Visible = false;
                    label1.Visible = false;

                }
            }
            Thread.Sleep(40);
        }
    }

    int isFiveSecond;

    private void m_timerFiveSecond_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (isFiveSecond == 5)
        {
            isFiveSecond = 0;
        }

        isFiveSecond++;
    }
```

Comment: First of all, a `lock` statement does nothing to prevent a collection from being modified while it's being enumerated, if the modification occurs in the same thread. Secondly, there are no collections in your code example, never mind any evidence of code that both enumerates and modifies any collection. Please fix your question so it includes a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: Could you tell me how I can do it with a sample code?

Comment: Do what? Asking for code examples and tutorials is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Here, you have asked a question, stating that an error is occurring, but you have failed to provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, which also makes the question off-topic. Please read the linked page, and [ask], and the other articles linked at the bottom of that page, to understand how to present a question in a clear, answerable way.